# Pandas csv export decimal values not correct

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Using python with pandas.
When exporting a dataframe to CSV all my decimal values become integers. For Example:

> 12.5487 become 125487

Which is no big deal for further calculations.

I tried :

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\export.csv',index=False, header=True,sep=',',decimal='.')
```

Won't work. I also tried to use the

> .astype(float)

Also no results.

This is the output of my df which shows the decimals as they should.

| GEG_BIO_EFFL | GEG_BUF1_LT_01 | BIO1_P01_OFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7003 | 5.895833 | 90 |
| 7004 | 5.789521 | 90 |
| 6894 | 5.654896 | 90 |

Can someone please tell me how to do this properly

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example _as text_ and also `print(df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: How did you determine the floats become integers? Did you open the file in a text editor or double-clicked it to open in Excel? CSV files are text files. Excel will *import* that text file using the current user's locale settings. I suspect the decimal separator on your machine is `,`, not `.`. Which is probably why you used `sep=',',decimal='.'`

Comment: @abokey The output is in the question above. and the return types of df.types are objects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I Have an other csv file which is also exported and my decimals are showing correctly without changing the settings. Thats makes it kinda weird.

Comment: @UwUs, I can't reproduce the issue with your given example/code. The dot between numbers is preserved in Excel (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzc5V.png) and in a Text Editor (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWGqN.png).